# Rifleman game with $n$ players in $D$ dimensions: what is the survivor fraction when $n,D\to\infty$?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, expectation, puzzle

This is a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459484/expected-number-of-people-to-not-get-shot/1484584) where the following problem is explored (for $D=2$):

> $n$ riflemen are distributed at random points in $[0,1]^D$. At a signal, each one shoots at and kills his nearest neighbor. What is the expected number $E_D[n]$  of riflemen who are left alive?

I explored the large $D$ limit numerically in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1484584/147873) which shows that $\frac{E_D[n]}{n}$ is an increasing function of $D$ (for any fixed $n$) which seems to be converging to some limit $f_n = \lim\limits_{D\to\infty}\frac{E_D[n]}{n} < 1$ and $f_n$ also seems to be an increasing function of $n$:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

If the box is periodic (making it a torus) we have the simple result $\lim\limits_{n,D\to\infty} \frac{E_D[n]}{n} = \frac{1}{e}$.

> My question is the following; what is the limit:
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{D\to\infty} \frac{E_D[n]}{n} = ~~?$$
>   i.e. what does the survivor fraction approch as $n,D\to\infty$?

I suspect it might be unity and the reason I belive this is because the corner effects (i.e. a player in a corner is less likely to be shot than a player in the center) become more and more prominent as we increase $D$. This can be seen by comparing with the case where we make the box periodic in which the results differ greatly for large $D$ (see the figure above). If we consider a $D$-sphere at the center of the box with radius $r=\frac{1}{2}$ then the volume of this sphere goes to zero as $D\to \infty$ so we would expect most particles to be in corner-regions for large $D$. The distance from a corner to another corner is always larger than the distance from a corner to the center. Thus in the some large $n,D$ limit I would roughly expect a typical situation to be something like one particle in each corner all shooting at the person being closest to the center giving us a survivor fraction that would be close to $1$.

> I'm unable to solve this so therefore I'm asking it here. I'm also interested in heuristical arguments that can shed some more light on this problem.

---

Some relevant papers in the litterature analyzing the rifleman problem (for more see references within the papers below):

1. ["The Rifle-Problem" R. Abilock; American Monthly; (1967)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2314274?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
2. ["Vicious neighbor problem" R.Tao and F.Y.Wu; J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 20 (1987)](http://nuweb9.neu.edu/fwu/wp-content/uploads/Wu111_JPA20_L299.pdf)
3. ["Nearest-Neighbor Graphs" S.R.Finch; Unpublished note; (2008)](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/nng.pdf)