# A disc contains $n$ random points. Each point is connected to its nearest neighbor. What does the average cluster size approach as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: probability, geometry, expected-value, geometric-probability, percolation

A disc contains $n$ independent uniformly random points. Each point is connected by a line segment to its nearest neighbor, forming clusters of connected points.

For example, here are $20$ random points and $7$ clusters, with an average cluster size of $\frac{20}{7}$.

[image]

> What does the average cluster size approach as $n\to\infty$ ?

**My attempt:**

I made a [random point generator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v4ziiyaonx?lang=zh-CN) that generates $20$ random points. The average cluster size is usually approximately $3$.

I considered what happens when we add a new random point to a large set of random points. Adding the point either causes no change in the number of clusters, or it causes the number of clusters to increase by $1$ (**Edit:** this is not true, as noted by @TonyK in the comments). The probability that adding a new point increases the number of clusters by $1$, is the reciprocal of the answer to my question. (Analogy: Imagine guests arriving to a party; if 25% of guests bring a bottle of wine, then the expectation of the average number of guests per bottle of wine is $4$.) But I haven't worked out this probability.

**Context:**

This question was inspired by the question [Stars in the universe - probability of mutual nearest neighbors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271497/stars-in-the-universe-probability-of-mutual-nearest-neighbors).

**Edit:** Postd on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462252/494920).

Comment: Adding a new point can actually _decrease_ the number of clusters. For instance, consider points on the $x$-axis at $0,4,9,$ and $13$: they form two clusters, $\{0,4\}$ and $\{9,13\}$. Now add a point at $x=6$: these five points form a single cluster.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is [Stars in the universe - probability of mutual nearest neighbors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271497/) in disguise. If there are $k$ pairs of mutual nearest neighbours, then there are $n-k$ edges (since $n$ edges are drawn and $k$ of them occur twice). There can’t be any cycles (unless it’s an Escher disk) because the distances would have to decrease all along the cycle. So the graph is a forest of $n-(n-k)=k$ trees. For $n\to\infty$, the fraction of points that are their nearest neighbour’s nearest neighbour goes to the probability for that to happen; $\frac kn$ is half that fraction, and the expected average cluster size is the reciprocal of that. In two dimensions, that yields

$$
2\left(\frac43+\frac{\sqrt3}{2\pi}\right)\approx3.218\;.
$$

Comment: ...which equals $(e+\frac12)\times 0.99991...$ Coincidence?

Comment: @Dan: Most likely, yes. I just saw that the same answer was already given at MO. Perhaps that was a slightly premature crosspost for a question like this after only half a day.

Comment: Guilty as charged :)

Comment: (+1) Amazing! I didn't expect that OP's question can be answered without knowing cluster-size distribution.

Comment: The numerical coincidence amounts to $13/6+\sqrt{3}/\pi\approx e$, with the latter only larger by about one part in 10000.

Comment: I suppose there is a *possibility* that there are 3 points forming a regular triangle, in which case they can form a 3-cycle. But the probability of that is infinitesimal.

Comment: @joriki By the way, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4850495/398708) is a new related question.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks. I think this is related to some ideas I had about learning more about the degree distribution of the nearest-neighbour graph, but they involve some complicated integration and it'll probably take a while before I work them out properly.

Answer (score 15):

Your question is scratching the surface of the area in probability called *percolation theory*.

Indeed, noting that the connectivity of a random graph in OP's model is independent of the scale, we may consider $n$ independent points sampled uniformly at random from a disk of radius $\sqrt{n}$. Then, as $n \to \infty$, the thermodynamic limit of this model converges to what is termed as the *nearest-neighbor continuum percolation* model [1], which can be described as follows:

> **Limit Model.** Let $X$ be a Poisson point process on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with constant intensity. For any two distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$, connect $x$ and $y$ if $y$ is a nearest neighbor of $x$.
>
> **Q.** Can we say anything about the cluster-size distribution in this model?

To my knowledge, it seems that most of the questions regarding this distribution, including OP's one, has never been explored in the literature, and I have a hunch that it is almost impossible to answer this exactly. At least, it is known that all the clusters are finite with probability one, as proved in [1].

---

**Edit.** [**@joriki** demonstrated that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4845566/9340) OP's question can be answered without explicitly knowing the size distribution of the connected clusters, via associating each cluster to the unique "mutual nearest-neighbor pair" contained in it.

---

**[1]** Häggström, O. and Meester, R. (1996), *Nearest neighbor and hard sphere models in continuum percolation*. Random Struct. Alg., 9: 295-315. [https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2418(199610)9:3<295::AID-RSA3>3.0.CO;2-S](https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1098-2418(199610)9:3%3C295::AID-RSA3%3E3.0.CO;2-S)

Answer (score 13):

This is a community wiki answer to provide a graphical demonstration of **@joriki**'s idea. (Feel free to expand this!)

In the image below, we generated $40$ random points. Then, from each point $x$, an arrow is drawn to its nearest neighbor $y$ along with the translucent disk of radius $\overline{xy}$ centered at $x$:

[image: Simulation]

It is clear from the picture that each graph contains exactly one "mutual arrow", visually confirming joriki's observation.

Below is the Mathematica code that is used to generate the above image:

```
n = 40;

(* Generate n points uniformly at random from the unit disk *)
pts = Table[Sqrt[RandomReal[]]*ReIm[Exp[2Pi*I*RandomReal[]]], {n}];

(* Construct the percolation graph *)
edges = Table[i -> Ordering[Table[If[j==i, Infinity, Norm[pts[[j]]-pts[[i]]]], {j,n}]][[1]], {i, n}]

(* Visualize! *)
Graphics[{
    {Directive[Dotted], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]},
    {FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[.1], Orange]], EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[.5], Orange, Thickness[Thin]]], Table[Disk[pts[[edge[[1]]]], Norm[pts[[edge[[2]]]]-pts[[edge[[1]]]]]], {edge, edges}]},
    {PointSize[Large], Red, Point/@pts},
    {Thickness[Medium], Arrowheads[Medium], Table[Arrow[pts[[List@@edge]]], {edge, edges}]}
}, ImageSize->640]
Clear[n,pts];
```

[Here](https://anematode.github.io/random-points/) is a simple JavaScript simulation intended for large $n$. (Note that it will not work on Safari.) For example, for $n=1359356$ it returns an average cluster size of $3.2174$.

Fun fact: As the number of points approaches infinity, the sum of areas of the pink discs approaches the area of the big disc (on which the points are randomly located). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851680/398708) is an intuitive explanation.