# $n\times n$ grid filled with $n$ colors. What is the average group size as $n\to\infty$

Tags: probability, geometry, expected-value, geometric-probability, percolation

Take a grid with dimensions $n\times n$ squares and randomly fill each square with $1$ of $n$ colors. What is the expected average group size of colors touching each other as $n$ approaches $\infty$? Groups of size $1$ count and they can touch either adjacently or diagonally.

For example, the following is a possible grid for $n=4,m=3$:

[image]

In this example, there would be $1$ group of size $4$, $2$ groups of size $3$, $1$ group of size $2$, and $4$ groups of size $1$. The average group size would be $\frac{16\text{ total squares}}{8\text{ total groups}}=2$.

I realize that the calculation for each iteration can be simplified to $\frac{n^2}{\text{total groups}}$ but I don't understand how to turn this problem into something that could be solved.

Here is the Desmos graph I created to test on my own: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ar9kohfdv3

I would offer an approximation but I can't figure out a way to calculate the total number of groups. This means I would have to count them manually and I would not be able to get very much data.

Motivation: This question was inspired by [A disc contains $n$ random points. Each point is connected to its nearest neighbor. What does the average cluster size approach as $n\to\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845153/a-disc-contains-n-random-points-each-point-is-connected-to-its-nearest-neighb?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For an arbitrarily chosen square, what is the probability that any of its neighboring squares is the same color? Hint: As $n\to\infty$ this probability is zero.